# Is there always at least one prime in the closed interval $[2^n,2^n+n^2]$?

Tags: nt.number-theory, prime-numbers

As an amateur, I honestly do not know what exactly to think about this question of mine. I know that there are arbitrarily large gaps between primes but do not know will they ever overlap with intervals of this kind, so that fact somehow goes in favor of that it could be that some intervals of this kind will not have primes inside (endpoints also count).

But as I also expect [Polignac's conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polignac%27s_conjecture) to be true it could be that there will always be at least one prime in $[2^n,2^n+n^2]$.

I do not know do these intervals grow too slow but I think they (in a certain sense) do, so somehow a counterexample seems to probably exist, if you ask me, but, again, I am not sure.

Feel free to close if I made a mistake again and asked a question not appropriate for MO.

Comment: For $n$ large enough, your conjecture follows from the Cramér's conjecture (see for example "Harald Cramér and the distribution of prime numbers" by A.Granville). Both conjectures (yours and Cramér's) seem to be extremely hard to prove.

Comment: Just to give you some idea of the difficulty of the problem, even proving the existence of primes in intervals $[2^n, 2^n + \sqrt{2^n}]$ is unsolved and considered to be extremely difficult.

Comment: The usual heuristic (suggested by the prime number theorem) is that the "probability" of a large number $N$ to be prime is about $1/\log N$. Accordingly, one can expect about $n/\log 2$ primes in the interval $[2^n,2^n+n^2]$. However, proving rigorously anything of this sort is completely out of reach, see the previous comment.

Comment: If you change the statement to almost every $n\in \mathbb N^*, [n,n+clog n]$, This morally could be look as a corollary of the result establish in "multiplication function and short interval" by Matomaki and Raziwill. But if you wish to consider a sparse set, I think this is out of the understanding.

Comment: Here's some recent computational data on record gaps between primes: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1309.4053.pdf

Comment: @Seva the same heuristic would "predict" $1/\log(2)$ primes in $[2^n,2^n+n]$, which of course cannot be an asymptotic behavior, i.e. at this scale there are oscillations. Is there any numerical evidence that the number of primes in $[2^x,2^x+x^2]$ divided by $x$ converges? or could there be oscillations at such a small scale?

Comment: @YCor: I don't speak about the asymptotic behavior but rather about the order of magnitude. However, it seems quite possible that $n/\log 2$ is also an accurate asymptotic. The numerical evidence is quite convincing: say, for $n=1000$ there are $1436$ primes in the range $[2^n,2^n+n^2]$, while $n/\log 2\approx 1442.695$ (the quotient is about $1.005$). As to the interval $[2^n,2^n+n]$ -- I do expect $\Theta(1)$ primes in average (and, maybe, $1/\log 2$ primes in average).

Answer (score 13):

As mentioned, this follows from an effective form of Cramér's conjecture, so we won't be able to disprove it.

But we won't be able to prove it either, because it implies the existence of an algorithm to find an $n$-bit prime in polynomial time, another open problem.  The algorithm searches for a prime using the AKS primality test by starting at $2^n+1$ and counting up until it finds one, requiring total time $n^{8+o(1)}$ if your conjecture is true.  But [the state of the art](http://michaelnielsen.org/polymath1/index.php?title=Finding_primes) in finding an $n$-bit prime is an algorithm requiring $2^{0.525 \cdot n + o(n)}$ time — in fact, it's the same algorithm, it's just not known to run any faster than that.